# Why do I get "identify not verified" when browsing https pages with Chrome (v42) on Shopify.com

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, shopify

It is specifically the checkout that concerns me:

https://checkout.shopify.com/5045549/checkouts/6321b0e319fdc3cab47b8ba2d1e30b46?_ga=1.255397768.1085821832.1430095488

When I'm on the cart page http://store.rockettags.com/cart and click the checkout button I'm taken to https://checkout.shopify.com and get the issue.

Why am I getting the issue and how do I fix it please?

I did a search and only found this info:  http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/identity-not-verified-in-chrome

Is it true that shopify.com is using out dated security settings.

See photo[image: certificate settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is reporting Shopify is using a SHA1 signed certificate as opposed to the new recommended SHA2 certificates.

Newer versions of Chrome [now warn against this](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.ca/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html).

Their Certificate Authority [does have SHA2 certificates available](https://www.digicert.com/sha-2-ssl-certificates.htm). So it may be a matter of Shopify needing to re-deploy their Certificates from DigiCert.

**EDIT:**

This appears to be a bug in Debian based (Debian, Ubuntu) distributions and this shouldn't happen on Windows. [More information here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=774195).

Shopify is indeed using the newer SHA-2 certificates which can be verified [here](https://shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com/check/checkout.shopify.com).

Comment: It's not an issue anymore with current Ubuntu 14.04, which already has the fixed  NSS 3.17.4. Maybe it helps if the OP just updates it's OS.

Comment: Martin - good effort thanks. I tried Windows (even same minor version of Chrome) and Mac with Chrome - didn't see the issue. They were happy. Where as on my ubuntu I always have the issue on the checkout. Interestingly some https urls at shopify can be made to work after a full browser cache clean but never the checkout regardless of what I do.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (without updates). Chrome version is 42.0.2311.90 (64-bit)

Comment: @ab16 - Try `dpkg -l | grep libnss` from your terminal. You will probably see a version of NSS just before the one @Steffen mentioned.